# Problem with adding custom CSS and JavaScript to a theme

Tags: theming

I know it is not new case, but I'm still stack about add custom CSS styles and JavaScript. I followed the official web's [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) but nothing  happened (not showing like trees and not showing error too although debug twig was enabled).

I want to add JavaScript and CSS to show structural trees. In `global-styling` and `global-js` all I need is defined completely, for example jQuery and Bootstrap from Drupal itself. Can you spot errors in the code?

#### mytheme.libraries.yml

```
treeview:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:     
      css/treeview.css: {}      

  js:
    js/treeview.js: {}
```

#### mytheme.info.yml

```
libraries:
  - mytheme/global-styling
  - mytheme/global-js
  - mytheme/treeview
```

#### twig-template.html.twig

```
{{ attach_library('mytheme/treeview') }} // I attach customed files(css & js) direct into twig-template.html.twig
```

#### Enable debugging Twig template

```
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
        debug: true
```

I tried this treeview without Drupal. It works perfectly.

Comment: Did you rebuild the caches?

Answer (score 0):

Add css and js in the global-styling:

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    base:
      css/treeview.css: {}
  js:
    js/treeview.js: {}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I have added on `global-styling` but still not work

Comment: Check  file path for both the files, Is it like  drupal/themes/custom/mytheme/css/treeview.css ?